# Is it possible to change arbitrary window title in KDE?

Tags: window, x11, kde-plasma

Is it possible to change window title of an arbitrary window that does not belong to my application (identified by application PID or window descriptor) in KDE? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: Related: [Override the window title for an arbitrary window in KDE and set a custom window title](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22561/5355)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone also searching for this, the above has helped me find the way to do this from the command line...

You will need to have *wmctrl* installed....

From the command line this can be achieved like this:
First (optionally) list all windows:

```
wmctrl -l
```

Then, assuming you have a window called "foo this is a window bar", issuing

```
wmctrl -r "this is a window" -N "Full new title"
```

will set the title of this window to *Full new title*

Comment: This works and is a lot simpler, thanks a lot :) *...if only I remembered what was this for...*

Comment: Also useful instead of specifying `wmctrl -r target_title -N new_name` you can specify `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE:`  to match the active window  `wmctrl -r :SELECT:` to select it with the mouse or use the -i option to use the window ID instead of the title

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done.

1. Iterate over the X11 Windows and check for one with the `_NET_WM_PID` property set to `PID`, yielding the `XID` of the window;
2. then change the `WM_NAME` property of that window.

But note that if this `_NET_WM_PID` property is not set by the program on its windows, you will not be able to find the window by the `PID`. And note that a program may set `_NET_WM_PID` on all of its windows, so the result of the first step may not be a single window.